# Keep listview colored while scrolling

Tags: android, listview

My listview has a button per line. When clicked I change this line color.
The problem is while scrolling it... return to default or other lines are colored.

The button listening is coded inside the adapter

```
public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<Map<String, String>> items, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, items, resource, from, to);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    final View line = view;
    TextView txtid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtid);
    TextView txtnumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtnumber);

    Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btncheck);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (txtnumber.getText().toString().equals(KEY-CODE)){
                line.setBackgroundColor(0x7F00FF00);
            }else {
                line.setBackgroundColor(0x7FFF0000);
            }
        }
    });        

    return view;
}
```

Comment: add the color to the item in the list you're using to load in the view and on click change it value of that item (you already get the position)

Answer (score 1):

I faced somthing like this once, you can save the state of the button using HashMap where the the boolean indicate the state of the button ( true if it was clicked and false otherwhise ), know inside getItemView check if current button is clicked or not from the HashMap.

A little bit of code :

inside getItemView first initialize each button to false (not clicked)

```
if(map.get(v.findViewById(R.id.button)) == null)  
      map.put(v.findViewById(R.id.button)),false);
```

and after clicking the button set the Boolean to true :

```
map.put(v.findViewById(R.id.button)),true);
```

and finally check if the Boolean is set to true or false and set the color.

Comment: and this case, need you reload it after click?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, what do you by mean reload it?

Comment: reload the list to assume new values for coloring